# Ignore a specific error

Tags: error

How to ignore a specific error (E303 in this case) globally?

(don't display it in the console)

I wish not to use try...catch if possible.

Comment: other than using `:sil!` and ignoring all errors, not possible.

Comment: Handling (in this case ignoring) is what try/catch is for...

Comment: For this special case, see `:help E303`. You might be able to prevent this error with a proper setting of the `directory` option.

Comment: I have set it. If I use noswap at some point when loading a saved session at least, it throws this error.